# friend locator app

Tags: java, sorting, interview-questions, hash-map

I was rejected after a tech screening for the following code.
I mainly struggled to make the code 'production ready'.
I was running out of time so I did not create a class for testing.
How could I have improved this code?

```
/*
Problem
Imagine you are building a friend locator app.
Given your current position identified on a bidimensional plane as (0,0) and a list of friend locations,
each identified by a (x,y) pair, return the k closest friends to your current location.

For simplicity, you can compute the distance between you and your friends using the Euclidean distance formula ( d = sqrt(x^2 +y^2) ).

Given a list of friend locations [[1,3], [-2,2]], K = 1
Output: [[-2,2]]
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/*
 * To execute Java, please define "static void main" on a class
 * named Solution.
 *
 * If you need more classes, simply define them inline.
 */

class Solution {
  
  static class Pair{
    int x, y;
    
    Pair(int x, int y){
     this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
      
  }
  
  /*
  d -> cords
  time - O(n)
  space - O(n)
  */
  public static List<Pair> closestFriends(List<Pair> list, int k){
    
  
    SortedMap<Double, Pair> map = new TreeMap<>();
    List<Pair> results = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    int i =0;
    
    for(Pair pair : list){
      double d = distance(pair);
      map.put(d, pair);
    }
    
    for(Map.Entry<Double, Pair> entry : map.entrySet()){
      if(i < k){
        results.add(entry.getValue()); 
        i++;
      }
    }
    
    return results;
    
  }
  
  public static double distance(Pair p){
    return Math.sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y);
  }
  
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Pair> cords = new ArrayList<>();
    cords.add(new Pair(1,3));
    cords.add(new Pair(-2,2));
    cords.add(new Pair(0,10));
    cords.add(new Pair(-2,2));
    cords.add(new Pair(1,3));
    cords.add(new Pair(-2,2));
    
    int k =1;
    /*
    empty list of cords
    negative k
    list list of cords
    test cases for distance - correct calculation      
    */
    
    List<Pair> res = closestFriends(cords, k);
    
    for(int i =0; i < res.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(res.get(i).x + "," +res.get(i).y); 
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: `class Solution {` is something I'd expect to see in a programming-challenge, not in production code. Was this provided by the company?

Comment: Why not use streams? It's a one-liner with streams... `return cords.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> Math.hypot(p.x, p.y))).limit(k).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 10):

### major issue: misunderstanding of exercise

you should find the **amount k** of friends - not the friends within an distanz k

### major issue: bug

```
for(Pair pair : list){
    double d = distance(pair);
    map.put(d, pair);
}
```

if two "pair"s have the same distance you'll lose one result

### major issue: naming

sounds obvious but you should create a `Position` not a `Pair` (also named in your exercise as `Location` - but never a `Pair`)

### minor issue: `Map` instead of a `List` (mostly assumption on this)

your exercise wants you to return a the first k items of a sorted list. I had expected you to use a `List` and create a `Comparator`, sort the list and then return the k first entries. you use a map to sort the element. and it's a buggy (see above) algorithm to sort.

### minor issue: Java coding conventions, not considering encapsulation

as example I say that `int x, y;` should be:

```
int x;
int y;
```

and formatting, use the spaces properly

### minor issue: naming

- when they give you the `amount k` you could pick up and rename that variable into a proper name
- when they give you a **list of friends** that you should filter rename that list properly

`public static List<Pair> closestFriends(List<Pair> friends, int amount)...`

another one here: I'm missing a proper *verb* in your method name: `getClosestFriends()` or maybe `findClosestLocations()`

Comment: Another major issue is naming number 3: `List<Pair> list` - I'd already kick the OP out of my office for that. Yes, we see from the data type that the variable is a list, there's no need to repeat this information in the variable name. But what does it contain, what does it signify? No indication.

Comment: yes, yes, very obvious, my bad i didnt see it! `List<Pair> list` should be named properly: `List<Pair> candidates` or `fiends` or similar (still `Pair` is improper)

Comment: @mtj i will add that point to the review

Comment: I don't get why you're saying the first major issue is that he misunderstood the exercise. Best I can tell, he did in fact find the K closest friends.

Comment: @MartinFrank tbh, in logner code the Data type in the declaration can be far away. My lists are named candidatesList (or similar), just to be on the very same side. Also makes it obvious at a glance whether that one line is referencing candidateS oder a candidate.

Comment: @Hobbamok whyen you use the Type as a variablen Name, this is called HungarianNotation. Things get bad when you change the type: then you have to rename the variablen name as well! (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and why this is always a point of discussion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation)